# Is there any iterator wrapper for forward and reverse iterators?

Tags: c++, iterator, type-erasure

In a passage of code, I have four `std::vector<T>::iterator`s: two normal iterators and two `reverse_iterator`— let's call them  `forward1`, `forward2` and `reverse1`, `reverse2` respectively.

I need to increment exactly one of these iterators based on an attribute of the object they're pointing at. Specifically, I need to increment the iterator whose corresponding object has maximal `x` value (where `x` is some field). Ideally, I'd do something like

```cpp
Iter iters[] = {forward1, forward2, reverse1, reverse2}

// increment the appropriate iterator:
Iter &it = *std::max_element(iters.begin(), iters.end(), [](Iter &lhs, Iter &rhs){ return lhs->x < rhs->x; })
++it;
```

But I can't find an appropiate base type or wrapper (denoted by `Iter` in the snippet above).

So, is there any way to do this without having to do something "manual" and ugly like below? Maybe something that extends to any number of iterators?

```cpp
if      (forward1->x < forward2->x and [...] and forward1->x < reverse2->x)
    ++forward1;
else if (forward2->x < forward1->x and [...] and forward2->x < reverse2->x)
    ++forward2;
// etc...
```

Also, I can't make use `reverse_iterator::base()` since I need to preserve the direction of the increment: that is, if the original iterator was reverse, I need to increment it as reverse, and viceversa.

And if I am to use `boost::any_iterator`, will the performance cost be significant? I'm doing this operation on a loop.

Comment: *"I can't make use `reverse_iterator::base()` since I need to preserve the direction of the increment"* You can store a flag alongside each iterator to indicate the direction of incrementing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following function `incrementMax` is a generic solution with C++14 and over.
This function increments the first one of `...args` storing the maximum value.

This function first generates value array `values` of `f(*iterator)`s and then find the position `idx` corresponding to the maximum value.
The function `increment` increments the iterator specified by it.
This function uses the array `arr` of the void function `increment_impl` and calls the `index`-th one of it:

```
template<int N, class Tuple>
void increment_impl(Tuple& t)
{
    ++std::get<N>(t);
}

template<class Tuple, std::size_t... Is>
void increment(Tuple& t, std::size_t index, std::index_sequence<Is...>)
{
    using void_f = void(*)(Tuple&);
    static constexpr void_f arr[] = { &increment_impl<Is, Tuple>... };

    arr[index](t);
}

template<class F, class ...Args>
void incrementMax(F f, Args& ...args)
{
    const auto values = { f(*args)... };
    const auto it = std::max_element(std::begin(values), std::end(values));
    const auto idx = std::distance(std::begin(values), it);

    auto t = std::forward_as_tuple(args...);
    increment(t, idx, std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Args)>{});
}
```

This is an usage example:

[**DEMO**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/4izCgVGusa1j5sSE)

[**DEMO (6 elements case)**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/IC2VjiIxzrHbkV85)

```
struct S
{
    int x;
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<S> v = {{1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {5}};
    auto forward1 = v.begin();    // 1
    auto forward2 = forward1+1;   // 2
    auto reverse1 = v.rbegin()+1; // 4, maximum
    auto reverse2 = v.rbegin()+2; // 3

    // 1243
    std::cout << forward1->x << forward2->x << reverse1->x << reverse2->x << std::endl;    

    // do ++reverse1;
    incrementMax([](const S& s){ return s.x; }, forward1, forward2, reverse1, reverse2);

    // 1233
    std::cout << forward1->x << forward2->x << reverse1->x << reverse2->x << std::endl;    

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> will the performance cost be significant?

Maybe. It depends. You have to measure to find out.

You could use `boost::iterator_facade` template - that is used to implement `any_iterator` - directly.

`std::variant<Iter, std::reverse_iterator<Iter>>` might be a lighter weight alternative for this use case.

Comment: A `struct helper : std::variant<It, reverse<It>>` that overrides `->` and `++` would be another clean option.

Answer (score 1):

```
template<class Scalar>
struct pseudo_it_ref_vtable {
  void(*inc)(void*) = 0;
  Scalar&(*get)(void*) = 0;

  template<class It>
  static pseudo_it_ref_vtable create() {
    return {
      [](void* pvoid){ ++*static_cast<It*>(pvoid); },
      [](void* pvoid)->Scalar&{ return **static_cast<It*>(pvoid); }
    };
  }

  template<class It>
  static pseudo_it_ref_vtable const* get_ptr() {
    static const auto vtable = create<It>();
    return &vtable;
  }
};

template<class Scalar>
struct pseudo_it_ref {
  using vtable_t = pseudo_it_ref_vtable<Scalar>;
  vtable_t const* vtable = nullptr;
  void* state = nullptr;
  pseudo_it_ref( pseudo_it_ref const& ) = default;
  pseudo_it_ref() = delete;
  template<class It,
    std::enable_if_t<!std::is_same<std::decay_t<It>, pseudo_it_ref>{}, bool> = true
  >
  pseudo_it_ref( It& it ):
    vtable(vtable_t::template get_ptr<It>()),
    state( std::addressof(it) )
  {}
  void operator++() { vtable->inc(state); }
  Scalar& operator*() { return vtable->get(state); }
  Scalar* operator->() { return std::addressof(**this); }
};
```

this is a simple type erasure type that can store a reference to any iterator on `Scalar&`.

```
pseudo_it_ref<int> iters[] = {forward1, forward2, reverse1, reverse2};

// increment the appropriate iterator:
auto &it = *std::max_element(iters.begin(), iters.end(), [](Iter &lhs, Iter &rhs){ return lhs->x < rhs->x; })
++it;
```

Probably there are simpler ways.

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9b04030791025e7b).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is anything in the stl that will do the job for you.

It sounds like you need to put together a simple helper class containing all your iterators, either hard-wired to take the four iterator of the types you need, or templated. The "cleverest" here would be to use a var-arg template that would accept any number of iterators, and a value comparator. The code also needs to cope as each iterator reaches end(). Actually it needs to know if they equal their end()s, so the constructor needs to be a list of iterator range pairs.

One question, though, as well as incrementing the lowest iterator, what else do you need to access about the iterator, or the value it represents? I.e. do you need to read the current lowest value, or do you need access to the iterator to access the whole object, e.g. the pair in a std::map? or to delete it?

The obvious reason to ask is because the class will only be able to return one type of object to represent the "current" iterated value. To do this you need to ensure that either all the iterators contain the same value object, or they are all derived from a common returnable iterator object.

Comment: This would be one option. I need access to the whole object.